# SQL Loader: column DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT : Not a valid month error

Tags: sql-loader

**1)** I am using SQL loader to load data in WDDRCUST table. Date column can have values such as blanks, '00000000' or real date values e.g. '20190830'. As per requirement, inserted Date should be null if it's not real date and I was using following to handle it in SQL Loader

```
DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT   POSITION (14825:14832)  DATE 'YYYYMMDD' nullif DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT = '00000000',
```

but it is failing and giving not valid month error when values are blank. Could you please share how I can resolve it? Help is much appreciated.

---

**1.b)** Also, If possible could someone please share how it can resolved using to_date function currently, I have few fields as following

```
DR165_AS_OF_DATE      POSITION (14572:14579)  "TO_DATE(TRIM(:DR165_AS_OF_DATE), 'YYYYMMDD')",
```

but it also failed in DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement:

```
   DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT   POSITION (14825:14832) DATE "YYYYMMDD" "CASE :DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT 
                                                                       WHEN '00000000' THEN NULL 
                                                                       ELSE to_char(to_date(trim(:DR165_LAST_PRINC_PMT_DT), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD' )
                                                                     END"
```